# Is there a function to retain the plots after changing other conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have the below code. Once I select "copen_cclose" the plot of "pclose_chigh" disappears. Is there a way to retain the plot "pclose_chigh" after selecting "copen_cclose". Can we retain the plots?

```
library(quantmod)
require(quantmod)
library(gdata)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library("gridExtra")

two_com <- c("3MINDIA.NS")

df1 <- as.data.frame(getSymbols(two_com, src = "yahoo", from = "2018-01-01", to = Sys.Date(), verbose = FALSE, auto.assign = TRUE))
allstocks <- fortify.zoo(`3MINDIA.NS`)

newcol <- c("Date","open","high","low","close","volume","adjusted")
colnames(allstocks) <- newcol

allstocks$MaxProfit <- round(allstocks$high - allstocks$low, digits = 1)
allstocks$day <- weekdays(allstocks$Date)
allstocks$month <- months(allstocks$Date)
allstocks$pclose_chigh1 <- round(c(NA, allstocks$close[-nrow(allstocks)]) - allstocks$high,digits = 1)*(-1)
allstocks$pclose_chigh1 <- as.numeric(as.character(allstocks$pclose_chigh1))
allstocks$copen_cclose <- round(allstocks$open-allstocks$close, digits = 1)

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("tab", sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            h6(selectInput("plots", "plots", choices = c("Null", "pclose_chigh", "copen_cclose"))),
            h6(selectInput("day", "Day", choices = c("Null", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"))),
            em(verbatimTextOutput("ST"))
        ),
        mainPanel(
            h6(plotOutput("message3")),
            h6(plotOutput("message2"))
        )
    )))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$message3 <- renderPlot({
        if (input$plots == "pclose_chigh") {
            qplot(pclose_chigh1, data = allstocks, geom = "density", colour = day)
        } 
    })
    output$message2 <- renderPlot({
        if (input$plots == "copen_cclose") {
            qplot(copen_cclose, data = allstocks, geom = "density", colour = day)
        } 
    })  
    output$ST <- renderPrint({
        if (input$day == "Monday") {
            shapiro.test(allstocks$pclose_chigh1[allstocks$day=="Monday"])
        }
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is rendering both plots every time `input$plots` changes.  Since you only have an `if` statement (and no `else` statement) the plots are only rendered if the condition is met. If not, nothing is rendered and the old plot is removed.

So either you add an `else` statement or you do something like this in your server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$plots, {
    if (input$plots == "pclose_chigh") {
      output$message3 <- renderPlot(qplot(pclose_chigh1, data = allstocks, geom = "density", colour = day))
    } else if (input$plots == "copen_cclose") {
      output$message2 <- renderPlot(qplot(copen_cclose, data = allstocks, geom = "density", colour = day))  
    }
  })

  output$ST <- renderPrint({
    if (input$day == "Monday") {
      shapiro.test(allstocks$pclose_chigh1[allstocks$day=="Monday"])
    }
  })
}
```